# Does Resharper's unit test explorer work with VB.NET test projects?

Tags: vb.net, testing, resharper, automated-tests

Does Resharper's unit test explorer work with test projects written in VB.NET?

In either case, does anyone have a reference to the JetBrains web site that mentions this?  My searching skills reveal nothing one way or the other.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "VB.NET Test Project". There are only "Test Projects", and they're all the same.

Comment: Uh, not sure what you mean--VB.NET projects are saved around a .vbproj file. (C# has a .csproj file, etc.)  I'll edit my question in case you aren't thinking what I'm thinking.

Comment: Yeah, but they're the same thing. There's no difference in the unit test features.

Comment: Does this martix make it any clearer? - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/editions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, it should work with them in the same way as with C# ones if you have the right ReSharper edition (full or VB.NET).

Comment: Great, thanks. Mine didn't work (the window is empty and won't populate).  I realized I was getting the same result in C#.  I investigated and noticed the "Enable unit testing" Resharper option needed to be checked.